# How does the Code of Conduct define expulsion?

Tags: support, deleted-users

[The current draft of the Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review) contains following image

[image: Report issues handling process]

which describes issues handling process. The last part states:

> Account Expulsion
>
> For very rare cases, or moderators will expel users displaying a pattern of harmful, destructive behavior toward out community.

How is the expulsion process implemented in practice? The terms of service vaguely mention that

> Stack Overflow may revoke your rights to the Network.

as well as it has

> right to pause or terminate your account

How exactly is the process of "termination" implemented?

I am aware of the [voluntary account process](https://stackoverflow.com/users/delete/8371915) -  is the same process used in that case?

If it is, doesn't it violate [network content license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)?

Comment: On [the announcement of the current draft of the CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312850), they ask that questions be asked on Meta Stack Exchange so that everyone can see the answers...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am not sure if it is that relevant to CoC (I believe its introduction doesn't affect existing procedure). But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Just above "Try not to worry..." there's a sentence "Please open all discussions here, on Meta Stack Exchange, so that everyone interested can find them in one place." I read that to mean they wanted discussions about the CoC to be on MSE only. I could be wrong.

Comment: @user8371915 Even if the concept of "expulsion" existed before the CoC (which it did, under a different name), it would still mostly be a [meta.se] question, as it's not specific to [so].

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks for pointing that out. The world outside Stack Overflow is still new for me.

Comment: Even if you get banned, couldn't you just make another account and start over with 1 rep?

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 Not the best idea. See "Can I simply create a new account?" on answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/1288408

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Expulsion is just a fancy way to say permaban. This might be implemented in two different ways at the moment, but they essentially do the same:

- If the user has no substantial contributions, their account is destroyed. In this case, all of their posts and actions become "user#######"'s, with the number corresponding to their pre-deletion account ID. [There's more to it than that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131666/), but essentially that is a flat out account deletion.
- More commonly, the user just gets suspended for 10/20/100/500 years network wide. The exact duration doesn't matter here, just that the user is essentially permanently banned.

Comment: Oh man. In 2518 when we're both still alive and kicking thanks to the mid-21st-century invention of immortality serum, we're gonna regret making such naive assumptions!

Comment: Has anyone been suspended for 500 years, or were you just throwing some numbers around?

Comment: @Dukeling for the 500, just some numbers to show it is arbitrary. I've seen 10 and 20 before though.

Comment: I feel like if you really want to permaban someone, 10 years isn't long enough. StackOverflow is already more than 10 years old.

Comment: Permaban -n. A fate worse than death.  -v. To punish someone with a permaban. In the words of Hermione: "I hope you're pleased with yourselves. We could all have been killed - or worse, permabanned."

Comment: @Dukeling: I actually think I saw a _crazy_ ban expiry date once. Only wish I could find it now

Comment: I see your '27 ban and raise you *['92*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1349035/ron-maimon).

Comment: @RobertColumbia: Wow, researching that user's behavior was an... interesting experience. People like that don't come along every day.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Seems like a bug to me, March 18 1992 was 25 years ago.

Comment: Why not simply use `float('+inf')`?

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut we're in the next century though, so referring to 2092 as '92 is counterintuitive yet arguably entirely correct

Comment: Is this sort of account pseudonymisation fully compliant with GDPR?